# Unable to access the login Button ..VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub login()
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim HTMLDoc As Object, HTMLDoc2 As Object
  Dim objCollection As Object

  Const navOpenInNewTab = &H800
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "https:///CWRWeb/displayMemberLogin.do"

  Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: Loop

  Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

  With HTMLDoc
  HTMLDoc.getElementByID("userID").Value = "yyyy"    'Entering credential
  HTMLDoc.getElementByID("passwd").Value = "xxxxx"
  End With


  Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementByID("login-s")
  objCollection.Click

End Sub
```

I am unable to automate the login click. The login button does not have an ID for input. I am not sure what to use to get the handle **.getElementBy....**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form has a name - you can submit it directly after you fill in the username and password

```
HTMLDoc.Forms("loginFormBean").submit
```

Comment: Was going to suggest this as well, but there could be javascript function attached to the button's click event.

Comment: Ran for me when I tested it

Comment: What does Form represent here??

Comment: What? Look at the document source - how did you find the userid/password elements? They're part of the same form that gets submitted (look for form name="loginFormBean"). Every document has a Forms element so that individual forms can be retrieved by index or name

Comment: You can see it in your own picture at the top - 10 lines up from your highlighted text